# Ordinal indicators in different languages in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, multilingual

I'm developing a multi-language website in PHP Laravel and I need to print on screen some sentences that shows numbers followed by an ordinal indicator.

The website is in English, Spanish, German, French, Italian, Portuguese, Russian, Polish.

I'm wondering if exist a way in php that can support me with the generation of the ordinal numbers in the different languages. Or some suggestions about how you would address this problem.

I spent quite some time googling but I didn't find any solution yet.

eg.

- English: 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ..
- Italian: 1°, 2°, 3°, ..
- French: 1er, 2e, 3e, ..
- Spanish: 1°, 2°, 3°, ..
- Portuguese: 1°, 2°, 3°, ..
- German: 1., 2., 3., ..
- Russian: 1-й, 2-й, 3-й, ...
- Polish: 1, 2, 3, ..

Comment: If that is a multi-language site, why not define these strings where you define all other multi-language content?

Comment: I was thinking to go for this solution if I don't find any smarter alternative. Already the  @Delena Malan way show me a viable path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a [`NumberFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class that you can use to format number for different [locales](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php).

You can create a formatter like:

```
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter("en-US", \NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);
```

and use it with `$formatter->format(3);`.

Here are some locales that I tried:

```
>>> $a = new \NumberFormatter("it-IT", \NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);
=> NumberFormatter {#3199
     locale: "it",
     pattern: """
       %%dord-mascabbrev:\n
       0: º;\n
       %digits-ordinal-masculine:\n
       0: =#,##0==%%dord-mascabbrev=;\n
       -x: −>%digits-ordinal-masculine>;\n
       %%dord-femabbrev:\n
       0: ª;\n
       %digits-ordinal-feminine:\n
       0: =#,##0==%%dord-femabbrev=;\n
       -x: −>%digits-ordinal-feminine>;\n
       %digits-ordinal:\n
       0: =%digits-ordinal-masculine=;\n
       """,
      …3
   }
>>> $a->format(12)
=> "12º"
>>> $a = new \NumberFormatter("en-US", \NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);
=> NumberFormatter {#3197
     locale: "en",
     pattern: """
       %digits-ordinal:\n
       0: =#,##0=$(ordinal,one{st}two{nd}few{rd}other{th})$;\n
       -x: −>%digits-ordinal>;\n
       """,
      …3
   }
>>> $a->format(12)
=> "12th"
>>> $a = new \NumberFormatter("fr-FR", \NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);
=> NumberFormatter {#3188
     locale: "fr",
     pattern: """
       %digits-ordinal-masculine:\n
       0: =#,##0=$(ordinal,one{er}other{e})$;\n
       -x: −>%digits-ordinal-masculine>;\n
       %digits-ordinal-feminine:\n
       0: =#,##0=$(ordinal,one{re}other{e})$;\n
       -x: −>%digits-ordinal-feminine>;\n
       %digits-ordinal-masculine-plural:\n
       0: =#,##0=$(ordinal,one{ers}other{es})$;\n
       -x: −>%digits-ordinal-masculine-plural>;\n
       %digits-ordinal-feminine-plural:\n
       0: =#,##0=$(ordinal,one{res}other{es})$;\n
       -x: −>%digits-ordinal-feminine-plural>;\n
       %digits-ordinal:\n
       0: =%digits-ordinal-masculine=;\n
       """,
      …3
   }
>>> $a->format(12)
=> "12e"
```

Comment: Does Russian work? I tried, but it doesn't seem to yield correct result.

Comment: for Russian shows 3. instead of 3-й, I'm not enough expert in Russian to get if it's ok or not..

Comment: I have no idea, sorry

Comment: I found this amazing library for Polish and Russian
https://github.com/arius86/number-formatter